Help, how to create spl token metadata without using umi?
Because when i deploy with UMI, i got this message from phantom wallet:

Email from blowfish:
If you want this warning to be immediately resolved, change your dApp to use the signAndSendTransaction method. Information about this method can be found here: https://docs.phantom.app/phantom-deeplinks/provider-methods/signandsendtransaction
I have tried convert my transaction, but i got error -32603 (Internal Error | Something went wrong within Phantom.)
My Code:
const createAndMintIx = createAndMint(umi, {
      mint,
      authority: umi.identity,
      name: metadata.name,
      symbol: metadata.symbol,
      uri: metadata.uri,
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
      decimals: Number(formData.decimals),
      amount: Number(formData.supply) * 10 ** Number(formData.decimals),
      tokenOwner: umi.identity.publicKey,
      isMutable: !immutable,
      tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    });

const instructions = [
        ...createAndMintIx.getInstructions().map(toWeb3JsInstruction)
      ];

      const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
        payerKey: toWeb3JsPublicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        recentBlockhash: (await connection.getLatestBlockhash()).blockhash,
        instructions,
      }).compileToV0Message();

      const transactionV0 = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

      const res = await provider.signAndSendTransaction(transactionV0);

if (res) {
        return {
          success: true,
          mint: mint.publicKey,
          message: "Token Created",
        };
      } else {
        return {
          success: false,
          message: "Transaction failed",
        };
      }


Could you share the error logs are you getting when the mint fails?

Here is a simple TS example minting fungible tokens with UMI

async function createAndMintFungible() {
    const mint = generateSigner(umi);

    // mint token
    let umiTX = await createAndMint(umi, {
        mint,
        authority: umi.identity,
        name: "Solana Gold",
        symbol: "GOLDSOL",
        uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/solana-developers/program-examples/new-examples/tokens/tokens/.assets/spl-token.json",
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(0),
        decimals: 6,
        amount: 1_000_000,
        tokenOwner: umi.identity.publicKey,
        isMutable: false,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.Fungible,
    }).buildWithLatestBlockhash(umi);

    // sign with the mint address and provider
    let signedTX = await signTransaction(umiTX, [mint, umi.identity]);

    //convert to web3 js TX
    const web3TX = toWeb3JsTransaction(signedTX);
    let txHash = await conn.sendTransaction(web3TX);
    console.log(txHash);
}

createAndMintFungible().then().catch(console.error);

The only way to add metadata to an SPL token is by using the mpl-metadata program. Metaplex only supports UMI as a TS client that you can use to interact with this program.
Alternatives

Use Token-22 with the metadata pointer
Create a program that CPI's into token metadata


it's works, but how if want to handle multiple transactions?

could you explain further?
